# VBA Out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an archive workbook once a column (V) is marked as "Yes". I had the macro functioning but when I tested it again this afternoon I received the out of range error. I have checked the names of my workbook/worksheet and they are correct. I've tried to troubleshoot but now when I select "Yes" in column V, the macro doesn't register at all. What could be the issue? Below is what I have been using. (I'm brand new to VBA and am teaching myself, so any help is appreciated!)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 22 Then
  If Target = "Yes" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
  nxtRow = Workbooks("FPPE Archive.xlsm").Worksheets("EUHM Onboard").Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Target.EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks("FPPE Archive.xlsm").Worksheets("EUHM Onboard").Range("A" & nxtRow)
   Target.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do `?Application.EnableEvents` in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't run is probably because during your testing you stopped the macro midway, and EnableEvents was not reset to True.

Comment: How do I remedy this?

Comment: In the VBE Immediate Window, Type: Application.EnableEvents = True, then press Enter

Comment: After I have closed/saved and reopen at a later time, I am still receiving the out of range error. Is there a permanent solution?

Comment: Did you move one of the files to a different folder? If yes, your macro will only work if both are currently open.

Comment: They're both in the same folder.